# Catalina upgrade leads to permanent "system has run out of application memory"

Tags: memory, bug, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina I get a permanent error message stating

> "Your system has run out of application memory"

which appears in a dialog that obscures my active windows.

This appears when I have a typical basic set of applications running. Prior to Catalina I was able to use the same set of applications, and then run additional applications (even heavy workload development applications) without any issues. This state of affairs continues even after quitting most apps:

[image]

Since this dialog repeatedly steals focus, it is now impossible for me to get any work done. How do I prevent this dialog from appearing?

Comment: What applications are you running when this occurs?

Comment: Finder, Mail, Safari, Calendar; or, as in the above image, just Finder.

Comment: This is certainly not usual for Catalina. Check how much RAM you have available, and being used, in Activity Monitor. Also how much free space on disk. I presume you have rebooted?

Comment: @benwiggy That's not the point though: this wasn't (ever) an issue at all, even with much (much) heavier workloads, before Catalina.

Comment: The point is getting it fixed. Just because it happens after installing Catalina doesn't necessarily mean the new OS itself is to blame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Your system has run out of application memory." How is that possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158639/your-system-has-run-out-of-application-memory-how-is-that-possible)